# How to Hex to Base64 in shell script (different output expected)?

Tags: shell, scripting

rookie IT shell scripting guy here.

I am looking to convert some HEX input into base64. I was trying to do the following but as you can see the output is different.

```
$ echo -n 6B255C065F0E5F105F115F0E0c58583C58583C583C3C5858585F100B31323334355F110355544F | base64
NkIyNTVDMDY1RjBFNUYxMDVGMTE1RjBFMGM1ODU4M0M1ODU4M0M1ODNDM0M1ODU4NTg1RjEwMEIz
MTMyMzMzNDM1NUYxMTAzNTU1NDRG
```

What I would like is to know how to get this encoding with the below expected output. 
input:`6B255C065F0E5F105F115F0E0c58583C58583C583C3C5858585F100B31323334355F110355544F`
output: **`ayVcBl8OXxBfEV8ODFhYPFhYPFg8PFhYWF8QCzEyMzQ1XxEDVVRP`**

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `xxd`:

```sh
$ xxd -p -r <<<'6B255C065F0E5F105F115F0E0c58583C58583C583C3C5858585F100B31323334355F110355544F' | base64
ayVcBl8OXxBfEV8ODFhYPFhYPFg8PFhYWF8QCzEyMzQ1XxEDVVRP
$
$ echo -n '6B255C065F0E5F105F115F0E0c58583C58583C583C3C5858585F100B31323334355F110355544F' | xxd -p -r | base64
ayVcBl8OXxBfEV8ODFhYPFhYPFg8PFhYWF8QCzEyMzQ1XxEDVVRP
```

Comment: Thank you! I didnt see this one before.